# Create fontawesome icon inside a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i want to append a fontawesome icon into the span that i just made as a var ..
Let's say I want to use this ""
Where and how can I use it? Thanks

```js
    var mySpan = $("<span />", {
        "text": "Spanned",
        "class": "myclass"
    });
    
    $("button").click(function(){
    mySpan.appendTo("div");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Click to Append</button>
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```js
var mySpan = $("<span />", {
  "text": "Spanned",
  "class": "myclass"
});

var myIcon = $("<i />", {
  "class": "fa fa-check"
}).prependTo(mySpan);

$("button").click(function() {
  mySpan.appendTo("div");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Click to Append</button>
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
var mySpan = $('<span class="myClass"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Spanned</span>')

$("button").click(function(){
    mySpan.appendTo("div");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Click to Append</button>
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert an `<i>` element inside your `span` - you can do this by manually making the element, or insert in the `html` property in your object:

```js
var mySpan = $('<span class="myClass">Spanned <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></span>')
$("button").click(function() {
  mySpan.appendTo("div");
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<button>Click to Append</button>
<div></div>
```

```js
var mySpan = $("<span />", {
  html: 'Spanned <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>',
  class: "myClass"
});
$("button").click(function() {
  mySpan.appendTo($("div"));
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<button>Click to Append</button>
<div></div>
```